# Swift - How to make a StackView 100% width

Tags: swift

Im trying to create a profile screen for an App. The only element that i cant get the width set dynamically is a 3 x 1 button grid in a stackview.

You can see in the second screenshot how it resizes rather than dynamically resize like every other element

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you used autolayout?

Comment: You can add a constraint of the width equal to superview's width to get 100% for that specific view.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Did you try checking with different setting in Distribution like equal center?

Comment: Please show the constraint of that grid view which you have added

Comment: Theres no constraints on the stackview

Comment: Then you will need to provide constraints else it will break in the different devices

Comment: Add leading and trailing constraint for stack view and so it will not go outside of your screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach. I made stack view which trailing and leading constraints are 0 and image height is set to 30 with aspect ratio 1:1 (this can be customized). Each image has its own View where its centered and then stack view aligment is set to center and distribution to fill equally. This can be used for buttons too.

[image]